# Calling a value from JSON in the controller in AngularJS so I can edit it

Tags: javascript, json, controller, angularjs, timeline

I am wondering if somebody can offer me help here.

I am working with a JSON file to create a timeline using AngularJS. I have been able to figure out how to output the date using the HTML binding ng-repeat loop, but I need to edit the date output; "2013-01-01" becomes "December 31, 2012" after I reformat it.

I have been struggling to figure out how to pull the date value IN THE CONTROLLER so that I can apply it in a function that will turn that value into the proper date -- by adding another day to the date as it is.

Thank you very much! I hope that made sense.

Comment: The date filter does this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date. If this is not what you need, can you post your controller code and some more context?

Comment: I have tried that but it isn't exactly working as I would like it. Here is what appears in my index view file:

    <h5>{{event.initialDate | date:'MMMM d, yyyy'}}</h5>

With event as the scope, and "initialDate" as the key value in my JSON. Let's say the value of this one particular "initialDate" is, for example, the string "2013-01-01". How it is outputted using AngularJS's date filter is this: "December 31, 2012". One date off. Do you have any ideas for to fix this? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript automatically localizes a date. The `date` filter in angular expects a timezone and when one is not provided assumes UTC. The issue is that once your timezone-less (thus assumed UTC) string gets localized, it is no longer precisely 2013-01-01, but however many hours shy of that your timezone is. Here in Pacific Standard Time, that's -8. So the date appears to be the day before.

Data from the server *should* have a timezone associated with it - that's just best practice. Without it, assuming UTC is a good bet. After all, *some* standard is needed.

Here's a Plunker showing a few examples of how this works, should you need them: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jhwnkj?p=preview

Comment: Wow, that answer makes everything so obvious now! That was much simpler than I expected. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @lisasy If this is the correct answer, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular date Filter in your view. You don't have to change any value in the controller.
Here is the example for you  http://plnkr.co/edit/iqIpW5uADTRVFycDxdBa

Read AngularJS date filter. 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Comment: That doesn't work for me -- http://plnkr.co/edit/iqIpW5uADTRVFycDxdBa

An input like this: $scope.inputdate = "2013-01-01"; reads as "December 31, 2012" still... Hmm.